# Google Maps Api v.3 Add 27,000 points to the map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

There is a task to place **27000** points of sale on google maps + clustering + infoWindow. At the moment, this is implemented through a normal loop for(point of poits){...} that adds markers to the map. There is a problem with high memory consumption and high load on the browser. I will be grateful for your help.

Answer (score 3):

I would take one of three approaches.

- Use the [WebGLOverlayView](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/webgl/webgl-overlay-view) - requires knowledge of WebGL and transformation s between coordinate systems
- Use a custom [OverlayView](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/overlay-view#OverlayView) - requires knowledge of DOM and transformations between coordinates and pixels
- Use [deck.gl](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/deckgl-points) - adds a bit of overhead to your application but provides a better dev experience for quickly iterating

The WebGL solutions will be higher performance but with added complexity or increase in bundle size.

This [sample](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/customoverlays) walks through adding an `<img>` to the map, but you can do much the same with some css positioning and many HTMLElements representing each point.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There is an example of the implementation of a similar task. I did not see anything extraordinary in the code, but everything works cool there. https://myglo.com.ua/pages/contact-us#go-buy https://prnt.sc/26niugi

Comment: Yes, markerclustering would be another options. https://www.npmjs.com/package/@googlemaps/markerclusterer